# Function consumes all gas using TestRPC, but is fine in JS VM

Tags: solidity, testrpc, out-of-gas, bug

So here's the function that's causing trouble:

```
function init() {
    require(! isInitialized);
    isInitialized = true;

    bytes32[] storage votableGroups;
    bytes32 fullTimeHash = keccak256('full_time');
    votableGroups.push(fullTimeHash);

    //Initialize voting types
    votingTypeList.push(VotingType({
        name: "Default",
        description: "For initializing",
        quorumPercent: 100,
        minForPercent: 100,
        activeTimeInBlocks: 25,
        goodRepWeight: 1,
        badRepWeight: 1,
        votableGroups: votableGroups
    }));
    votingTypeList[votingTypeList.length - 1].isEligible[fullTimeHash] = true;
}
```

It always consumes all gas when I'm testing it using Truffle and TestRPC, but it works just fine when I'm using the JavaScript VM in Remix. The function runs fine when I commented out the last two statements.

I can't see anything wrong with my code, so is this caused by a bug in TestRPC?

Comment: Is `votableGroups` a contract variable? because it is never initialized otherwise. What is the definition of VotingType?

Comment: @Ismael It's a local variable. How do you initialize it?

Comment: @Ismael VotingType's definition is `struct VotingType {
        string name;
        string description;
        uint quorumPercent;
        uint minForPercent; //Minimum proportion of for votes needed to pass the voting.
        uint activeTimeInBlocks; //The number of blocks for which the voting is active.
        uint goodRepWeight;
        uint badRepWeight;
        mapping(address => uint) tokenWeights; //From token's address to weight
        mapping(bytes32 => bool) isEligible; 
        bytes32[] votableGroups; 
    }`